# Как вставить виджет "Modal" внутрь виджета "GridView" yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, виджет

Друзья, помогите, нужно, чтобы превьюшка отображалась в модальном окне при клике на "view" button в виджете ActionColumn (который внутри виджета GridView).

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'author_id',
        'name',
        'date_create:datetime',
        'date_update:datetime',
        'preview',
        'date',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Подозреваю, что можно настроить как то `['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']`, чтоб превьюшка отображалась в модальном окне. Но как? Есть где-то в доках инфа об этом?

Я представляю, что это должно выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
...
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\bootstrap\Modal',
                    'header' => '<h2>Hello world</h2>',
                    'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'click me'],
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

Но это лишь моя фантазия, которая не находит подтверждения в документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меня устроил этот код:

```
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Загруженная книга:</h2>',
]);

echo '<div id="author"></div><div id="name"></div>';

Modal::end();

     <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'name',
            'preview',
            'authorName',
            'date_create:datetime',
            'date',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'buttons' => [
                    'view' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        $options = [
                            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'View'),
                            'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'View'),
                            'data-toggle' => Yii::t('yii', 'modal'),
                            'data-target' => Yii::t('yii', '#w0'),
                        ];
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, $options);
                    },
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
```

И js:

```
$("body").on("click", "a[href*='book/view']", function(e){   

    $.ajax({
        url: this,                             
        dataType : "json",                     
        success: function (data) {                
            $(".modal-body #name").html(data.name);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Принял свой вариант, т.к. он более полный и ближе к практическому решению задачи. Нужно сказать, что соседний вариант, так же работоспособен.

Answer (score 1):

Код `['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']` в `GridView` работает следующим образом:

`ActionColumn` наследуется от `Column` и в методе `renderDataCellContent` возвращает контент который будет в итоге отрендерен. Изменяя публичные свойства `ActionColumn` мы можем влиять на то что он будет рендерить. Принцип работы здесь такой же как и в остальных настройках - передача массива параметров. Например так:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'buttons' => [
        'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            return $model->status === 'editable' ? Html::a('Update', $url) : '';
        },
    ],
];
```

Это пример кода из документации класса `ActionColumn`. В вашем случае вы можете просто сделать так:

```
[
    'label' => Yii.t('frontend', 'View'),
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function (MyModel $model) {
        echo Html::a('View', ['view', 'id' => $id], [
            'id' => 'gridViewId_' . $id //Теперь в JS можно написать метод который вместо редиректа выведет модальное окно.
        ]);
    },
],
```

Также можно заценить крутое расширение [yii2-grid](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid). Модальных окон там нет, но может быть вам пригодится иной его функционал.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже сделал чуть иначе. И проще, чем вы предлагаете. Поэтому ваш вариант принять не могу, но спасибо сказал ;)

Comment: @Razzwan ништяк :) Можете ответить на свой же вопрос и рассказать как вы решили задачу.

Comment: да, так и сделаю. Возможно, кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Хотя, возможно ваш код более верный, как ответ на данный вопрос. Пусть повисит в таком виде - может кто еще оценит решения. Если что ваш ответ примем ;)

Comment: @Razzwan у вас уже работающее решение, принимайте как ответ смело :)